# Fill part of circle with background color

Tags: html, css

Here is [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eh5qspq1/2/.)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="for">
    <span class="no">67%</span>
    <span class="fill" style="height: 67%" />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.for {
  border-color: green;
  color: green;
  margin-right: 6px;
}
.against {
  border-color: red;
  color: red;
   border-radius: 100%;
}

/* For first circle*/
.fill {
  background: greenyellow;
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.against {
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

I want to fill background of the circle with background color of the element that has height in percent.

I've managed to do this with square element.

Thanks

Comment: Your fiddle already does what I think you are looking for. Are you looking to avoid the background being visible outside the circle? If yes, add `overflow: hidden` to the `div`.

Comment: You could use some JS here http://jsfiddle.net/eh5qspq1/6/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your circle is already filled. 
Give  `overflow: hidden;` to `.for`

```
.for {
    border-color: green;
    color: green;
    margin-right: 6px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eh5qspq1/4/)**

Comment: Thanks! That was it, I really dont know how I miss this :(

Comment: @glad to help. Accept it as answer by clicking on right symbol then.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can add this:

```
.for{    background: linear-gradient(transparent 33%, greenyellow 1%);}
```